# list of public ips along with subsciption name, resource type in Azure using Azure Resource Graph

Tags: azure, kql, kusto-explorer

I need to get a list of public ips along with subsciption name, resource type (such as vm, application gateway, elb) in Azure using Azure Resource Graph. I would also like to display the public ip addresses as well.

This is my draft but I don't know how list other resources:

```
Resources
| where type =~ 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
|project name, OS=tostring(properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType), location, 
ipid = tolower(tostring(properties.networkProfile.networkInterfaces[0].id))
| join kind=leftouter (
    Resources
    | where type =~ 'microsoft.network/networkinterfaces'
    | project ipid = tolower(id), elasticPoolName = name, 
    publicIPid = properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.publicIPAddress.id)
    | join kind=leftouter (
        Resources
        | where type =~ 'microsoft.network/applicationGateways'
        | project name, publicIP
on ipid
| project-away ipid
| project name, OS, location, pubipid=tolower(tostring(publicIPid))
| join kind=leftouter (
    Resources
    | where type =~ 'microsoft.network/publicipaddresses'
    | project pubipid = tolower(id), publicIP = properties.ipAddress)
on pubipid
| project-away pubipid
| project name, publicIP, OS, location
```

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query to get the associated resource providers for all the IP addresses:

```
Resources
| where type contains 'publicIPAddresses' and isnotempty(properties.ipAddress)
| project name,id= split(properties.ipConfiguration.id,"providers",1),ip_address=properties.ipAddress
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:**

> - As You can see in the above image , we get a output of providers
>   with the name in the id part for example
>   `/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/kubernetes/frontendIPConfigurations/0713fba8-23fa-43bc-a003-b4197500b399`,
>   then it means that the Public IP is associated with a `Load balancer` with name `kubernetes` as shown in 1.
> - If the association is with network interface , then the network interface might be associated with a Compute resource (like VM etc) or
>   a DNS as shown in 2.
> - If it is not associated with any resource then it gives back `null` as shown in 3.
> - In 4 it is being used by Bastion Host.
> - In 5 its being used by a VNET Gateway.